# Content of webpage is cut off in UIWebView

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uiwebview, scaling

I'm having some difficulties with the content of a WebView.
It seems like the left part of the webpage is cut off, but in in safari on the iPhone it is properly displayed (pictures 1 and 2). The constraints are set correctly. I also tried to move the UIWebView out of the PageViewController, but the page was still cut off. This problem seems to occur only when this page is opened.

It is possible to scroll to the right, but if I try to scroll to the left the page is cut off, as I already said.

Code of the UIWebView:

```
class LoginWebViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {

//MARK: CLASSES
let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

//OUTLETS
@IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!
@IBOutlet weak var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!

//IDENTIFIERS
let mainAppCycleSegueIdentifier = "showMainAppCycle"

/**
Assigning Delegates
*/
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    webView.delegate = self

}

/**
Detecting correct URL for segue!
*/
func webView(webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: NSURLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {

    let URLString = request.URL?.absoluteString

    if URLString!.containsString(RESPONSE_URL) {
        print("Token URL Loaded!")
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier(mainAppCycleSegueIdentifier, sender: self)

        if !userDefaults.boolForKey("HasLaunchedOnce") {
            userDefaults.setBool(true, forKey: "HasLaunchedOnce")
        }
    }

    return true
}

func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
    activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
    let url = webView.request?.URL?.absoluteString
    if url!.containsString(URL_WHERE_THE_PROBLEM_OCCURS) {

    }
}

/**
Automatically loading starting URL once the View appears
*/
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

    let URLforRequest = NSURL(string: URL_TO_THE_AUTHENTICATION_SERVER)

    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: URLforRequest!)

    webView.loadRequest(request)
}
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

edit:

Since I don't have enough reputation to post more than 2 links, I had to put them into a document on google drive: [Document with links on Google Drive](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1YWMFUVGm4BI0dPe4aGS8u0szuYi406FcN5p5Dl9VIsw/edit?usp=sharing)
It only contains links to images on imgur regarding this question.

Comment: It seem to me this is related to the way your laying out the view in your .storyboard/.nib file. Would you mind providing some screenshots of those?

Comment: @BellAppLab Thanks for responding. Unfortunately I'm not able to post more than 2 links, so I put them into a document on GoogleDrive. I hope that I made a screenshot of the things you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

```
// I hope you it will work 
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()

  webView.delegate = self
  webview.scalesPageToFit = true
 // webview.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleToFill /* try with different options as per your requirement UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill,UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but if someone else has this problem like I did, I figured out that the webview rect was bigger then the view size. The code was grabbing the bounds of a full screen view controller but it should get the bounds from the parent.

Changed to grab the correct bounds and everything works perfectly fine.

I suggest you put a breakpoint in there and check the webview frame and match it with your real frame.